# php cannot seem to insert data into mysql database

Tags: php

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here, but I'm having hard time trying to insert data from a form into the database.

Here is my table

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `accounts` (
  `accid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `acc_number` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `cust_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `cust_tel` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `cust_address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `cust_opendate` date NOT NULL,
  `cust_openamount` decimal(13,2) NOT NULL,
  `cust_balance` decimal(13,2) NOT NULL,
  `cust_message` text NOT NULL,
  `cust_openby` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`accid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

The $_session['username'] is set and the database is included and working.
when i fill the input and click the submit i get the message New account has been added.

```
<?php
session_start();

$success = array();
$errors = array();

include('header.php');

if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    include_once('libs/db-con.php');

    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $accNumber = $_POST['accnumber'];
        $custName = $_POST['custname'];
        $tel = $_POST['tel'];
        $addess = $_POST['address'];
        $openDate = $_POST['opendate'];
        $openAmount = $_POST['openamount'];
        $balance = $_POST['balance'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $openBy = $_SESSION['username'];

        if (empty($accNumber) || empty($custName) || empty($tel) || empty($addess) || empty($openDate) || empty($openAmount) || empty($balance) || empty($openBy))
        {
            $errors[] = 'All fields are required';
        }else{
            $query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO accounts(accid, acc_number, cust_name, cust_tel, cust_address, cust_opendate, cust_openamount, cust_balance, cust_message, cust_openby)  VALUE(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            $query->bindValue(1,$accnumber);
            $query->bindValue(2,$custName);
            $query->bindValue(3,$tel);
            $query->bindValue(4,$address);
            $query->bindValue(5,$openDate);
            $query->bindValue(6,$openAmount);
            $query->bindValue(7,$balance);
            $query->bindValue(8,$message);
            $query->bindValue(9,$openBy);

            $query->execute();

            $success[] = 'New account has been added';

            }
        }



        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT max(acc_number) FROM accounts");

                $query->execute();

               while($num = $query->fetchAll()){

                if($num[0] == null){

                $accnumber = "100001";

                }else{

                $accnumber = $num[0]++; 
            }    
        }       
?>

           <div class="today-acc">
            <h3>create new account</h3>
            <div id="form-newacc">
                <form action="" method="post">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="accnumber">Account No:</label><input type="text" name="accnumber" value="<?php echo $accnumber[0]; ?>"></td>
                        <td><label for="custname">Name:</label><input type="text" name="custname"></td>
                        <td><label for="tel">Tel:  </label><input type="text" name="tel"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="address">Address:</label><input type="text" name="address"></td>
                        <td><label for="opendate">Open date:</label><input type="text" name="opendate" id="datepicker"></td>
                        <td><label for="openamount">Open Amount:</label><input type="text" name="openamount"></td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="balance">Balance:</label><input type="text" name="balance"></td>
                        <td><label for="message">Message:</label><textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea></td>


                    </tr>

                </table>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Create">
                        <input type="reset" name="reset" Value="clear">
                </form>
                <?php foreach ($success as $successes) {
                    echo '<div id="success">'.$successes.'</div>';
                }?>
                <?php foreach ($errors as $error) {
                    echo '<div id="errors">'.$error.'</div>';
                }?>
            </div>
            </div>

<?php

}
else{

        header("location: login.php");
    }
         ?>
```

I updated the code. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you get an error message, or what happens?

Comment: No errors? Is `$_SESSION['username']` set? Are the includes working? Is `$_POST['submit']` set? In other words.. could be anything. Turn on your errors and find out.

Comment: no errors at all and $_SESSION['username'] is set

Comment: Props for using prepared statements.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to insert into 10 columns:

```
accid, acc_number, cust_name, cust_tel, cust_address, cust_opendate, cust_openamount, cust_balance, cust_message, cust_openby
```

But you only got 9 question marks:

```
?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?
```

IT's recommended not to use question marks since it can lead to simple errors like these, it's better to do something like

```
"INSERT INTO accounts(accid, acc_number, cust_name, cust_tel, cust_address, cust_opendate, cust_openamount, cust_balance, cust_message, cust_openby)  VALUE(:accid, :acc_number, :cust_name, :cust_tel, :cust_address, :cust_opendate, :cust_openamount, :cust_balance, :cust_message, :cust_openby)"
```

If accid is indeed not suppose to receive a value, instead it shall receive an automatic incremented value, then you should not mention it in your query.

**EDIT:**

Some thoughts:

1: You check if the session of the username exists with this

```
isset($_SESSION['username']
```

but where's the else? You are not doing anything if the username is not set anywhere, try to output some errors that would indicate that the user is not logged in.

2: You assume that the query will work if you execute it, you can never be sure that an executed query will be true.

Instead if supposing that it's always true, like you're doing here:

```
$success[] = 'New account has been added';
```

Then you must check whether the insert query returns true or false, you can return error message if the executed query returns false.

```
$inserted = $query->execute();
$inserted ? $success[] = 'New account has been added' : $success[] = 'New account has not been added';
```

I'm using the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a) in the end, you should take a look at it.

Comment: I removed the accid and its still the same

Comment: Well this is a start, I'll look better at it.

Comment: why he need to check the username session while he doesnt have any users yet? weird !

Comment: I'M going to update the code above and include the form so you can see the complete code.

Comment: That's not the point. Maybe he's a user creating a new user, you can't be sure, that's his implementation, I'm just saying what he should do if his implementation is correct. Did you down vote this, @k0sh

Comment: In a way, but it didn't fix his problem :(

Comment: yeah and btw. it seems that i clicked the upvote and down vote and i can't change what i did unless you edit your post. could you please edit it so i take back my downvote?

Comment: Should be change-able now.

Answer (score -1):

```
     $blahblah = mysql_query("INTO accounts(accid, acc_number, cust_name, cust_tel,   
cust_address, cust_opendate, cust_openamount, cust_balance, cust_message, cust_openby)VALUE(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)") or die(mysql_error());
```

you are inserting 9 instead of 10 columns !

**Edit**

```
 $blahblah = mysql_query("INTO accounts VALUE('','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?')") or die(mysql_error());
```

> ```
>   `accid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
> ```

the ID must be EMPTY as its auto inserted by your database.! **and you are also inserting Char to an Int column.**

Comment: I removed 1 column and nothing change still the same. its weird

Comment: He has already mentioned that he skipped the accid column in his insert query so your edit is pointless.

Comment: @Jonast92 i re-edit my post !. he was given the ID a char while its int

Comment: @k0sh He was never giving it a value, how could he be giving him a char if he was never inserting anything?

Comment: when he did this             $query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO accounts(accid, acc_number, cust_name, cust_tel, cust_address, cust_opendate, cust_openamount, cust_balance, cust_message, cust_openby)  VALUE(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
 its obvious that the first inserted value is the accid, which when he inserted the 9 chars to the database, its ordered base on his selection at the insert stage. so when he said Value(?) as the first one then the database automatically will think that he inserting to the accid DUUUUH

Comment: @kaneo please see my edits and check my comments here and see where is your vault. its obvious give what i edited a try and let me know.

Comment: He alr said that he removed the accid so it won't change anything.

Comment: @Jonast92 i'm talking about the second edit !!! which doesn't have the id inserted but auto generated !!! EMPTY.

Comment: @k0sh i tried your second edit and removed the accid column. its still the same. i want to post the complete code including the form. how do i do that?

Comment: just click on Edit href at the bottom of your first post and then update it with your code.